# Virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper seem to not work

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, virtualenv-commands

A few months ago I installed `virtualenv`, `virtualenvwrapper` and `pip`, created a few virtual environments and played with Django successfully.

After returning to my projects today, I am unable to use any of these commands. For instance:

> /> lsvirtualenv

returns:

> / >

Further:

> / > workon

also returns:

> / >

What might be the reason for this? Folder `.virtualenv` is located here `/users/myUser/documents/projects/.virtualenvs` and its contents are:

```
get_env_details
postactivate
postmkproject
postrmvirtualenv
predeactivate
premkvirtualenv
initialize
postdeactivate
postmkvirtualenv
preactivate
premkproject
prermvirtualenv
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These commands are generated by the script `virtualenvwrapper.sh`. You have to source that file in order to get the commands.

Try this:

```
find / -name "virtualenvwrapper.sh" 2>/dev/null
```

It should find and return the filepath. On my system it is:

```
/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

So you can do:

```
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Now you should have the commands. Probably you'd like to have these commands without sourcing `virtualenvwrapper.sh` everytime you boot your system.

Add that line to your `.bashrc` (or alternatively in `.bash_profile` or `.profile`), along with two other lines

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Projects
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

After that create the directory `Projects` (you can call it whatever you want and place it whereever you want) manually:

```
mkdir $HOME/Projects
```

After the next start you should have all the commands and the new environment variables. When you do:

```
mkproject foo
```

new directory foo will be created:

```
.virtualenvs/foo
```

and:

```
Projects/foo
```

The first one is your virtual environment, the second one is where your projects lives. With `workon foo` you can activate it, and with `cdvirtualenv` and `cdproject` you can switch between them.

EDIT:

After rereading your question, I think the problem might be eventually with the way how you created the virtual environments.

The commands `lsvirtualenv` and `workon` are provided by `virtualenvwrapper`. If you create your virtual environments with the comand `mkvirtualenv` (also provided by `virtualenvwrapper`) then `lsvirtualenv` and `workon` will list them.

But if you create them like this:

```
virtualenv foo
```

`virtualenvwrapper` won't be aware of your virtual environments.